# Gasoline not flowing after 2 days of not using

Tags: motorcycle, gasoline

I have rider 150 fu motorcycle and it has open carburator.
After using it and not using it in the next 2 days the gasoline ia not flowing anymore, so i need to push or blow air from the tank to let the gasoline flow.
Or pull(absorb i think to pull the gasoline from the tank from its gasoline passage) so it might work again.
I wondering what could be the solution so that i don't do this everytime. Its become more hassle and delay the time specially when in a hurry.
But if i use it eveyday there is no problem.
Some people said there is salt forming if the gasoline is not flowing because it is open carb.